# Is there a way to remove the Push Notification Pop Up confirmation message in Fastlane screenshots?

Tags: swift, push-notification, screenshot, fastlane

I'm creating snapshots using Fastlane. As my application uses "Push Notifications", when the app is launched it always displays to the user the pop up that requests the authorization to send this kind of messages. There is a method that is called in the AppDelegate `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()`, this method is the one that "shows" the pop up to the user.

I have tried something like:

```
#if !DEBUG
  UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
#endif
```

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
#endif
```

I also tried to set a Global variable but it hasn't been possible to find a place where to set this variable, because it never works

I always get the same behavior.

I would expect that the first time I run the test in the simulator, it does not display the message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy way to avoid this screenshot.

Before the screenshot is taken, I simply press the button "Allow"

```
let systemAlerts = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard").alerts
if systemAlerts.buttons["Allow"].exists {
   systemAlerts.buttons["Allow"].tap()
}
```

Simple an easy :)